# nx run-many --target=test --coverage but exclude one project from coverage

Tags: code-coverage, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Is it possible to exclude one project (name it ProjectA) from coverage with `nx run-many --target=test --coverage`?

--exclude won't work as I still need UT result of ProjectA. ProjectA is expected to have very low code coverage rate, that I don't want to include into a code coverage summary of whole workspace.

Setting `collectCoverageFrom` to `!**` in ProjectA's jest.config.js somehow works, but `nx --coverage` command still generate code coverage result 0/0.

I could also split original command into two

```
nx run-many --target=test --all
nx run-many --target=test --all --coverage --exclude=ProjectA
```

but it's waste of time to run test twice.

Is there a better solution? Is it possible to configure a project differently with `nx run-many` command?

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude app. This should work:

```
nx run-many --target=test --all --exclude xy-app
```

From help (*npx nx run-many --help*):

```
  run-many --target=test --projects=*-app --exclude excluded-app  Test all projects ending with `*-app` except `excluded-app`
```